# How to install packages libtiff4-dev and liblcms1-dev?

Tags: apt, package-management

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

I want to install dependencies for django project.

When i try, (here are dependencies)

```
sudo ./install_os_dependencies.sh install
```

It prints an error

```
Package libtiff4-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
libtiff5-dev:i386 libtiff5-dev

Package liblcms1-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libtiff4-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'liblcms1-dev' has no installation candidate
```

How to install above packages?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev liblcms1-dev`?

Comment: Yes! It prints the same ==> E: Package 'libtiff4-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: Have you tried doing `sudo apt-get install libtiff5`?

Comment: Yes! It was successfully installed, dependencies need libtiif4!

Comment: libtiff4 does not exist in 16.04. You can install 14.04, or ask the project maintainer to make it compatible with 16.04.

Comment: You suggest me to move Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed packages. 
I just changed the names of packages in requirements.apt

from `libtiff4-dev`
to `libtiff5-dev` and

from `liblcms1-dev` to `liblcms2-dev`

Because my ubuntu 16.04 don't use libtiff4-dev and liblcms1-dev